# Creating universal simple Makefile for compiling c++

Tags: c++, makefile

I'd like to have universal Makefile.

```
ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
        test.exe: test.cpp dog.o
                g++ test.cpp dog -lws2_32 -o test.exe
else
        test: test.cpp dog.o
                g++ test.cpp dog -o main

dog.o: dog.cpp dog.h
        g++ -c dog.cpp
```

This gives me:

`Makefile:5: *** recipe commences before first target.  Stop.`

Can anybody help me to create that?

Comment: "universal" "simple" and "Makefile" simply don't go together. Take any two. If it's universal and simple, it's not a Makefile. If it's a universal Makefile, it's not simple. And if it's a simple Makefile, it's not universal. Choose your poison.

Comment: `test` is the name of a standard command on Linux systems, so is a bad name for your program

Comment: one way of having "universal" makefile is to create library of template targets. Have a look at https://github.com/igagis/prorab/blob/master/wiki/TutorialBuildApplication.md for my implementation of such library.

Answer (score 1):

Make use a declaritive style:

```
PLAT_FLAGS_Windows_NT  = -lws2_32
PLAT_FLAGS             = $(PLAT_FLAGS_$(OS))

EXE_NAME_Windows_NT    = test.exe
EXE_NAME               = $(EXE_NAME_$(OS))
EXECUTABLE_NAME        = $(if $(EXE_NAME), $(EXE_NAME), main)


test.exe: test.cpp dog.o
   g++ test.cpp dog.o $(PLAT_FLAGS) -o $(EXECUTABLE_NAME)

dog.o: dog.cpp dog.h
   g++ -c dog.cpp
```

Note: Don't forget tabs are important in Makefiles and the web interface does not like tabs so you may have to add them back in.

Answer (score 0):

You've got 2 errors in that Makefile:

`Makefile:5: *** recipe commences before first target.  Stop.`

Rules need to start in the first column so unindent the `test.ext`/`test` lines.

Fixing that leaves:

`Makefile:10: *** missing 'endif'.  Stop.`

`ifeq` needs an `endif`. See below for a mostly working version.

```
ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
test.exe: test.cpp dog.o
        g++ test.cpp dog -lws2_32 -o test.exe
else
test: test.cpp dog.o
        g++ test.cpp dog -o main
endif

dog.o: dog.cpp dog.h
        g++ -c dog.cpp
```

Comment: If you must use a `ifeq-else-endif` then only set variables inside. Move the rules outside and use variable to substitute the correct values. It will make the Makefile a lot easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

the `ifeq` is processed by make before the make file is "executed". it is kind of like the preprocessor in c. so everything between `ifeq` and `else` (or `else` and the missing `endif`) is copied verbatim to the "postprocessed" Makefile. That is why you must format the code lines as if they are written without the `ifeq`. So no indent and especially no indent by tab because tab is a special character for recipes.

```
ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
<no tab here>test.exe: test.cpp dog.o
<tab here>g++ test.cpp dog -lws2_32 -o test.exe
else
<no tab here>test: test.cpp dog.o
<tab here>g++ test.cpp dog -o main
endif

dog.o: dog.cpp dog.h
        g++ -c dog.cpp
```

read here for more information: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Example.html#Conditional-Example

Comment: If you must use a ifeq-else-endif then only set variables inside. Move the rules outside and use variable to substitute the correct values. It will make the Makefile a lot easier to read.